# Sorting a list of tensors by their length in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a list of tensors in the form `list = [tensor([1,2]), tensor([3, 4, 5])]` and would like to order it in descending order based on the length of the tensors. This means the sorted list should look like `list = [tensor([3, 4, 5]), tensor([1, 2])]`.

Using `.sort(key=length)` does not work, and have also tried using `.sort(key= lambda x: len(x))` unsuccessfully.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? `list.sort(key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)` is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using python built-ins (`list`) for your variable names.

you can sort like following:

```py
list_tensors = [torch.tensor([1,2]), torch.tensor([3, 4, 5])]

print(sorted(list_tensors, key=lambda x: x.size()[0]))
```

which will output :
`[tensor([1, 2]), tensor([3, 4, 5])]`

Or in descending order :

```py
list_tensors = [torch.tensor([1,2]), torch.tensor([3, 4, 5])]

print(sorted(list_tensors, key=lambda x: x.size()[0], reverse=True))
```

output :
`[tensor([3, 4, 5]), tensor([1, 2])]`